An inequality about the image of holomorphic functions on unit disk
Suppose $f:\mathbb{D} \to \Omega$ is a holomorphic surjective function on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$,with $f'(z)\neq 0 $ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Show that $\text{dist}(f(0),\partial\Omega)\leq |f'(0)|$.
I 've got a proof if f is bijective:
Assuming that $f(0)=0$,then $f^{-1}$can be a holomorphic function from $B(0,d)$ to $\mathbb{D}$,where $d=\text{dist}(f(0),\partial\Omega)$.Take $g(z)=f^{-1}(dz)$,then $g$ is a holomorphic function from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ with $g(0)=0$,and Schwarz Lemma tells that $|g'(0)|=\frac{d}{|f'(0)|}\leq 1$.
I wonder if this is right for $f$ is not bijective or there is a counter example.

$\text{dist}(f(0),\partial\Omega)\leq f'(0)$ needs a correction.

Sorry,it’s $|f’(0)|$.And do you have any idea?

What is $\Omega$?

$\Omega$ is an arbitrary region,thus a connected open set in $\mathbb{C}$.

Are you sure that it's the derivative that is supposed to have no zeros? I think I have a short prrof in case $f$ itself has no zeroes in $D$ except at $0$ itself.

By translation, rotation, and scaling we can assume wlog $f(z)=z+\sum_{k \ge 2}a_kz^k$ and let $r$ the radius of the largest (open) disc centered at $0$ and included in $\Omega$. We need to prove that $r \le 1$ so assume by contradiction that $r>1$.
Let $W=f^{-1}(\mathbb D_r)=\cup W_k$ where $W_k$ are the connected components and $W_1$ is the one such containing $0$. We claim that $W_1$ is simply connected and $f$ is a biholomorphism from $W_1$ onto $\mathbb D_r$.
If this is proven then with $g$ the inverse of the above so $g(0)=0, g'(0)=1$, we have $g(rz)$ maps $\mathbb D$ onto $W_1$ hence into $\mathbb D$ and zero to zero, so by Schwarz Lemma $r=|rg'(0)|\le 1$ and we get a contradiction with $r>1$ and we are done!
Let's prove the claim. Consider a local inverse $g_1$ of $f$ near $0$ (exists because $f'(0) \ne 0$) so $g_1(0)=0 \in W_1$ and consider a (nice) curve $C$ in $\mathbb D_r$ starting at $0$ and continue $g_1$ on it, which can be done since $f' \ne 0$ so $f$ has local inverses at every image point. Clearly, the image of any such continuation lies in $W_1$ by connectedness. But $\mathbb D_r$ is simply connected so by the monodromy theorem the continuation doesn't depend on the path so defines an analytic function $g$ on $\mathbb D_r$ that maps onto $W_1$ and is inverse to $f$ there. Hence $W_1$ is biholomoprhic to $D_r$ (so simply connected) and $f$ realizes one such bilohomoprhism and the claim is proved.
